# Regex for 3 3-digit values separated by a period

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a regex for a software version field which has the following format :

xxx.yyy.zzz

These 3 parts can have between 1 to 3 digits each. Ex :

```
1.2.3
100.2.300
111.222.333
```

I formulated this regex for this purpose , but it's incorrect :

```
[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}
```

What should be modified to get it working correctly ?

Comment: `var re = /[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/g; `

Comment: @Tim007 Thanks for the comment. You can provide it as the answer and I'll mark it as accepted .

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your input too , but since I had no idea of escaping dots , I'd be going with Tim's answer ...

Comment: @user2991608 ok thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
```

or

```
[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oT8fR7/)

Javascript

```
var re = /\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/g;
```

or

```
var re = /[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/g;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the dots in the regex, otherwise they count as any character.

```
var regex = /[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/;
regex.test('1.2.3'); //true
regex.test('100.2.300'); //true
regex.test('111.222.333'); //true
```

If you don't escape the dots, you will be able to provide any character in the place of the dot.

```
var badRegex = /[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}/;
badRegex.test('1a2z3'); //true
badRegex.test('100-2#300'); //true
badRegex.test('111f2229333'); //true
```

Answer (score 2):

You should escape dot with `\` and also you can use `\d` which means digit

`\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}`